# Simple response to the user's input in WPF

Tags: wpf, user-interface, dictionary, input

There's a WPF page which is made for the questionary program. Questions and answers are taken from the resouce file so all GUI elements are placed during runtime.

There's one label for the question body, answers can be simple label, dropdownlist or multiple textedits(or single). If there are more than 2 answers, radio button or checkbox are added to each depending on the question type. I have classes Question(for questions, question object contains its answers), Answer(for variants) and Result(where all user's answers are stored).

Now to respond to user's input(toggle button check/uncheck, textedit text changes(when it changes, toggle button if exists automatically have to be checked), dropdownlist value changes) I have to store 3 huge dictionaries(Dictionary, Dictionary, Dicrionary) to quickly respond to the user's input. Is there more simple way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dynamic binding from the value of the answer control (combo,radio...etc) to a property in the question class. On that property you could do some validation using IDataErrorInfo. Is this going in the direction you want ?